# Implementing C++ template-like behavior in C#

Tags: c#, templates

I have an assignment in a language-independent class, and part of it is using templated functions like

```
    T functionName(T &param1[], T &param2[]){
        // do stuff
    }
```

I would like to write this program in C#, but I've ran into a problem.

How can I make this work in C#:

```
<pre><code>
T functionName(ref List<T> param1, ref List<U> param2){
    // do stuff
}
</code></pre>
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you intended param2 to be `List<U>`

```
T functionName<T,U>(ref List<T> param1, ref List<U> param2)
```

Otherwise:

```
T functionName<T>(ref List<T> param1, ref List<T> param2)
```

Answer (score 3):

You've got two answers that cover generics... just an aside: it is unusual is C# to need `ref`, since you are already passing just the reference (`List<T>` is a reference-type object). The `ref` is needed only if you are assigning new lists inside the method and want the client to see the re-assignment. Changes to the list(s) will already be seen without the `ref`.

Comment: Yup, I was going to post this if you hadn't.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (note the **`<T,U>`** after the function name):

```
T functionName<T,U>(ref List<T> param1, ref List<U> param2){
    // do stuff
}
```